# Extend an existing nginx location

Tags: nginx, lua, proxypass, openresty

I have a location within my nginx configuration that I want to be left unchanged by my clients. But I still want them to give the possibility to extend the subpaths.

What I will define:

```
location /root {
   access_by_lua_block {
      var headers = {};
      require(my_script).protect(headers);
   }

   proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1;
}
```

Something like this for them

```
location /root/subpath {
  access_by_lua_block {
      var headers = {}; //some extra headers
      require(my_script).protect(headers);
  }

  And now run the complete location /root also and then do the proxy_pass of root to 127.0.0.1/root/subpath
}
```